# Error consulta desde php, function bind_param()

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Necesito ayuda con esto:

```
   <?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');
   include_once 'includes/funciones/funciones.php';
  session_start();
   usuario_autenticado();
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
      $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
      $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
      $hora = $_POST['hora'];
      $id_cat = $_POST['categorias'];
      $id_invitado = $_POST['invitado'];

      require_once('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');

      if ($conn){
        $strSQL="SELECT cat_evento, COUNT(DISTINCT nombre_evento) FROM eventos INNER JOIN categoria_evento ON eventos.id_cat_evento=categoria_evento.id_categoria WHERE id_cat_evento = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($strSQL);

        if ($stmt){
            $stmt->bind_param('i', $id_cat); //Si $id_cat es numérico debes cambiar la "s" por una "i"
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($categoria_evento, $total);
            $stmt->store_result();
            $stmt->fetch();
            (int) $total = $total;
            $total++;
            $clave = substr($categoria_evento, 0, 5) . "_" . $total;
            echo $clave;
        }else{
          echo "Consulta errónea ".$stmt->error;
        }

    }else{

      echo "La conexión es nula";
    }

  }else{

     echo "No hay datos en submit";
  }

 ?>


 <?php include_once 'includes/templates/header.php'; ?>


                <section class="seccion contenedor">
                    <h2>Agregar Evento</h2>
                    <p>Bienvenido <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']; ?> </p>

                <?php include_once 'includes/templates/admin-nav.php'; ?>

                <form class="invitado" action="agregar_evento.php" method="post">

                    <div class="campo">
                        <label for="nombre">Nombre Evento:</label>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="campo">
                        <label for="fecha">Fecha Evento:</label>
                        <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="campo">
                        <label for="hora">Hora Evento:</label>
                        <input type="time" name="hora" id="hora" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="campo">
                      <label for="categoria">Categoria: </label><br>
                    <?php
                      try {
                        require_once('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');
                        $sql = "SELECT * FROM `categoria_evento`";
                        $res = $conn->query($sql);
                        while ($cat_eventos = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
                          echo '<input type="radio" name="categorias" value=' . $cat_eventos['id_categoria'] . '> ' . $cat_eventos['cat_evento'] . '<br/>';
                        }
                      } catch (Exception $e) {
                        echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
                      }
                      ?>
                    </div>

                    <div class="campo">
                      <label for="invitado">Invitado:</label>
                        <?php
                          try {
                            require_once('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');
                            $sql = "SELECT `invitado_id`, `nombre_invitado`, `apellido_invitado` FROM `invitados`";
                            $res_invitados = $conn->query($sql);
                            echo "<select name='invitado'>";
                            while ($invitados = $res_invitados->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                              <option value="<?php echo $invitados['invitado_id'] ?> ">
                                <?php echo $invitados['nombre_invitado'] . " " . $invitados['apellido_invitado']; ?>
                              </option>
                          <?php }
                            echo "</select>";
                          } catch (Exception $e) {
                            echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
                          }
                        ?>
                    </div>

                  <div class="campo">
                    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Agregar" class="button" >
                  </div>
                </form>


                <?php $conn->close(); ?>
                </section>


     <?php include_once 'includes/templates/footer.php'; ?>
```

este es el codigo sin la inserción de su codigo

```
       <?php
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
  ini_set('display_errors', '1');
      include_once 'includes/funciones/funciones.php';
      session_start();
      usuario_autenticado();
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])):
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
    $hora = $_POST['hora'];
    $id_cat = $_POST['categorias'];
    $id_invitado = $_POST['invitado'];

    try {
      require_once('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');
      $stmt = $conn->prepare(" SELECT cat_evento, COUNT(DISTINCT nombre_evento) FROM eventos INNER JOIN categoria_evento ON eventos.id_cat_evento=categoria_evento.id_categoria WHERE id_cat_evento = ?");
      $stmt->bind_param('d', $id_cat);
      $stmt->execute();
      $stmt->bind_result($categoria_evento, $total);
      $stmt->store_result();
      $stmt->fetch();
      (int) $total = $total;
      $total++;
      $clave = substr($categoria_evento, 0, 5) . "_" . $total;
      echo $clave;

      header('Location:agregar_evento.php?exitoso=1');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
      echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
    } /**/
  endif;
  ?>

  <?php include_once 'includes/templates/header.php'; ?>


                      <section class="seccion contenedor">
                          <h2>Agregar Evento</h2>
                          <p>Bienvenido <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario']; ?> </p>

                      <?php include_once 'includes/templates/admin-nav.php'; ?>

                      <form class="invitado" action="agregar_evento.php" method="post">

                          <div class="campo">
                              <label for="nombre">Nombre Evento:</label>
                              <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="campo">
                              <label for="fecha">Fecha Evento:</label>
                              <input type="date" name="fecha" id="fecha" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="campo">
                              <label for="hora">Hora Evento:</label>
                              <input type="time" name="hora" id="hora" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="campo">
                            <label for="categorias">Categoria: </label><br>
                          <?php
                            try {
                              require_once('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');
                              $sql = "SELECT * FROM `categoria_evento`";
                              $res = $conn->query($sql);
                              while ($cat_eventos = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
                                echo '<input type="radio" name="categorias" value=' . $cat_eventos['id_categoria'] . '> ' . $cat_eventos['cat_evento'] . '<br/>';
                              }
                            } catch (Exception $e) {
                              echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
                            }
                            ?>
                          </div>

                          <div class="campo">
                            <label for="invitado">Invitado:</label>
                              <?php
                                try {
                                  require_once('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');
                                  $sql = "SELECT `invitado_id`, `nombre_invitado`, `apellido_invitado` FROM `invitados`";
                                  $res_invitados = $conn->query($sql);
                                  echo "<select name='invitado'>";
                                  while ($invitados = $res_invitados->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $invitados['invitado_id'] ?> ">
                                      <?php echo $invitados['nombre_invitado'] . " " . $invitados['apellido_invitado']; ?>
                                    </option>
                                <?php }
                                  echo "</select>";
                                } catch (Exception $e) {
                                  echo "Error:" . $e->getMessage();
                                }
                              ?>
                          </div>

                        <div class="campo">
                          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Agregar" class="button" >
                        </div>
                      </form>


                      <?php $conn->close(); ?>
                      </section>


      <?php include_once 'includes/templates/footer.php'; ?>
```

este es el error

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on
>   boolean in
>   E:\Users\Bitnami\apache2\htdocs\gdlwebcamp\agregar_evento.php:19 Stack
>   trace: #0 {main} thrown in
>   E:\Users\Bitnami\apache2\htdocs\gdlwebcamp\agregar_evento.php on line
>   19

imagen del phpMyadmin
![consulta tabla]: https://photos.app.goo.gl/x15Yj7HcVLsKN1t13

Comment: Prueba cambiar la `"s"` por `1`

Comment: Yikarus, gracias por responder. pues cuando hago la consulta en MySql  ||" SELECT cat_evento, COUNT(DISTINCT nombre_evento) FROM eventos INNER JOIN categoria_evento ON eventos.id_cat_evento=categoria_evento.id_categoria WHERE id_cat_evento = ? "||

Comment: @Yikarus eso es en Java, en PHP se debe poner `s` si la columna es de tipo cadena (`s`tring), `i`, si la columna es del tipo entero (`i`nteger)... Lo que indica el error es que `$stmt` es `false`, porque no se creó el objeto `$stmt` en la preparación. Algo falló y su valor actual es `false`.

Comment: colocando el 2 al final de la consulta, pero mi idea del BIND_PARAM("s", id_cat) es traer el string desde la inserción en la pagina

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function bind_param() on
> boolean

indica que la variable `$stmt` cuyo método `bind_param` intentas llamar aquí:

```
$stmt->bind_param("s", $id_cat);
```

tiene un valor booleano. Eso significa que cuando preparaste el `$stmt` algo salió mal y su estado actual no es un statement, sino que es `false`.

Dos cosas pueden estar ocurriendo.

### Primera

Que la conexión es nula.

Eso es muy fácil de verificar, además, es la práctica recomendada. Evaluar siempre el valor de la conexión antes de usarla.

### Segunda

Que haya un error en la consulta: Error de sintaxis, error en nombre de una tabla, de una columna mal escrita, etc. Es algo a evaluar también en todo código para saber lo que ocurre.

### Código implementando ambas soluciones

No puso el `try`... porque en el trozo de código compartido no tiene sentido. No sé si lo uses para otra cosa.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
/*  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($_POST);
  echo "</pre>"; */
  $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
  $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];
  $hora = $_POST['hora'];
  $id_cat = $_POST['categorias'];
  $id_invitado = $_POST['invitado'];



    require_once('includes/funciones/bd_conexion.php');

    if ($con){
        $strSQL="SELECT cat_evento, COUNT(DISTINCT nombre_evento) FROM eventos INNER JOIN categoria_evento ON eventos.id_cat_evento=categoria_evento.id_categoria WHERE id_cat_evento = ?";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($strSQL);
    
        if ($stmt){
            $stmt->bind_param("s", $id_cat); //Si $id_cat es numérico debes cambiar la "s" por una "i"
            $stmt->execute();
            $stmt->bind_result($categoria_evento, $total);
            $stmt->store_result();

        }else{
            
            echo "Consulta errónea ".$stmt->error;
        
    }
    
    }else{
        
        echo "La conexión es nula";
    }    
    
}else{
    
    echo "No hay datos en submit";
}
```

> **NOTA:** Si a pesar de esto no funciona revisa que no haya algún problema con la conexión a la base de datos o con el framework o
> programa que estés usando para construir tus aplicaciones.

Comment: Los comentarios no deben usarse para discusiones extendidas; esta conversación ha sido [trasladada a un chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67867/discussion-on-answer-by-a-cedano-error-consulta-desde-php-function-bind-param).